# Copy and Remove textarea1 to another textarea2. working already

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

code already working tnx to @Maurice Perry and others. html and jquery Function (copy and remove text from dropdownlist and move to another textarea)

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <title> Example</title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">                      </script>  
      <script>
     $(function(){
     $("#copy").on("click", function(){
     $("#textarea option:selected").each(function(){
     $("#textarea2").append($(this).clone());
     $(this).remove();
        });  
     });   
      $("#remove").on("click", function(){
      $("#textarea2 option:selected").each(function(){
      $("#textarea").append($(this).clone());
      $(this).remove();
          });  
         });  
       });
     </script>
     <body>

    <select multiple="multiple" class="options" id="textarea">
     <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
     <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
     <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
     <option value="item4">Item 4</option>
     <option value="item5">Item 5</option>
    </select>

     <button id="copy">Copy</button>
     <button id="remove">Remove</button>

     <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove">
     </select>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: I don't see any text areas here, just dropdown lists with ids "textarea".

Comment: He means that names of select are textarea and textarea1

Comment: @HanletEscaño it has a 1 dropdown list and 1 textarea

Comment: like @DanielGrankin says

Answer (score 1):

Or this?

```
$(function(){
    $("#copy").on("click", function(){
        $("#textarea option:selected").each(function(){
            $("#textarea2").append($(this).clone());
            $(this).remove();
        });  
    });   
    $("#remove").on("click", function(){
        $("#textarea2 option:selected").each(function(){
            $("#textarea").append($(this).clone());
            $(this).remove();
        });  
    });  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/3BN6v/

EDIT

Import jquery in your page:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title> Example</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ...
```

Comment: thanks this i need:)) but still cannot run in notepad++

Comment: this? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: in jsfiddle it works but mine still cant run propely no copy and remove function

Comment: on the top page @maurice Perry i just replace the my <script> to your <script> function and nothing change

Comment: Add jquery before the <script> tag then

Comment: can you show me what should i change and what should i put tnx

Comment: ow Ok ill try it again tnx ill message you again tnx

Comment: Still copy and remove function dont work. i just copy all the codes on the top page then replace the jquery function and put jqueryscript. but still dont work.

Comment: http: was missing. Sorry about that

Comment: it works:))) tnx for your help. functions now all working copy and remove function:) tnx for all the help:)

Comment: tnx for helping again:)

Answer (score 0):

You have fogot to add jquery to your page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For removing use this

```
$("#remove").on("click", function(){
              $("#textarea option:selected").each(function(){ 
                   $(this).remove();
             });  
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#copy").on("click", function()
{    
    $("#textarea2").append($("#textarea option:selected").clone());
});

$("#remove").on("click", function(){
    $("#textarea2").append($("#textarea option:selected"));
});
```

Those should provide a copy and a move functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/3qyMJ/1/

Comment: tnx ill try this and ill comment soon tnx

Comment: Escano but how about copy only no move? copy/remove functions?? tnx

Comment: The first button in the example (look at jsfiddle) should be only copying without removing.

Comment: Escano yes tnx for this but still cant run properly in notepad ++

Comment: What do you mean it cant run in notepad ++ ? This is a page, run it on Chrome or Firefox or IE.

Comment: escano
imean in JSfiddle it works fine but when i transfer it to notepad++ function button wont work. my codes are on the top page i just change the <script> functions

Comment: You just gotta make sure you wrap your code in `$(function(){//code here});` otherwise it won't work. Fiddle does that for you behind the scenes.